# Moment.js issue if trying to set date on 1.1. for actual year

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to get date for first day of the new year, it means that I tried something like this:

```
dateFrom = moment().month(0).day(01).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But it gives me date:

```
2013-12-30
```

Instead of the

```
2014-01-01
```

How can I solve it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `date` instead of `day` if you want to define the day of the month.

This works:

```
moment().month(0).date(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

- The `date` method defines *day of the month*, [docs here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/).
- The `day` method defines the *day of the week*.  [From the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/):

So, by using `day(1)` you are asking to get the nearest Monday.  In your case the nearest Monday to `January 1st, 2014` is `December 30th, 2013`